# Flask file does not work after deactivation and reactivated. "Flask can't be found"?

Tags: flask, pip

Using Visual Studio Code
1. installed python3:
    - "python3 --version" -->returns Python 3.7.4
 2. installed virtualenv
    - "pip3 install virtualenv"
    - "virtualenv env"
    - "virtualenv --version"  --> returns 16.7.4
 3. activated virtual environment
    - "source env/b/activate"  --> creates (env) note at terminal prompt correctly
 4. installed flask in virtual environment
    - " pip3 install flask"
 5. In the python shell, `import flask` does not return an error.
 6. python program is:
...
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__ name __)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    - return 'Hello, World!'
...

I get an error!
 7. the error is: "unable to import flask"

### ANY IDEAS ARE APPRECIATED.  THANK YOU

I using the following to run program:

### export FLASK_APP=flask_blog.py

pip show flask  --> returns:  flask not found
pip3 show flask --> returns: flask version 1.1.1
pip doesn't find flask but pip3 does.  What does that mean?

Comment: what's your `which python` command output ?

Comment: This could be several easy-to-remedy things, but first we'll have to know how, exactly, you created the virtual envirnment, and how, exactly, you're trying to launch the Flask app.

Comment: Can you post the python program you're running. At least the first few lines. For starters, your import syntax you mentioned seems incorrect. It is `from flask import Flask` and not `import flask from Flask`

Comment: And how do you *run* this file?

Comment: And. How. Do. You. *Run.* This. File?!

Comment: i try: export "FLASK_APP=flask_blog.py" or "python3 flask_blog.py" and neither works.